# How to make a divider to be responsive / to auto resize on different screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, autoresize, divider

In my page i use some dividers from this website:
http://www.dcodes.net/2/docs/divider.html

and all look good , but when i access the page from mobile phone in vertical position , the dividers don't resize automatically (ar too long),
so my question is:

how to make them responsive , to auto resize on different screen size?

Comment: Please provide details in your post. Relevant code is important.
Just a guess, give the image a CSS style of width: 100%;

Comment: Why not simply make your divider's width 100%?

Comment: You also might not be able to do so with these dividers as they are custom styles someone else made. If they didn't make them responsive, you probably won't be able to make them responsive yourself without recreating them or editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

They don't resize because the stylesheet they provide has a `width: 600px` defined on the `.dc_divider1` rule. That rule is fine for desktops, but 600px on most mobile devices is too much.

If you add another property to the `.dc_divider` rule to limit the width, it will display properly on mobile devices. The rule to add is the `max-width: 100%;` rule. Whenever a mobile device tries to render the background image, the `max-width` rule will prevent it from being wider than the mobile screen.

Example:

```
.dc_divider1 {
    background:url(../images/dc_divider1.png) no-repeat scroll center transparent;
    height:35px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:6px;
    width:600px;

    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS vh and vw with as in "max-width:95vw;"

Answer (score -1):

On mobile (or any screen width thinner than the divider):

```
.child {
  margin-left: -50%;
}
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/ctsmxs98/2/